# Topology modeling

Tags: modeling, topology

I can see, many different way to modeling, as long as there 4 edges, but in this case is it just my way to tweak the vertices which is not good or just this kind of topology which is not adapted to this corner ?

[image: Wave]

[image: topology]

Comment: you could try looking here: http://polycount.com/discussion/56014/faq-how-u-model-dem-shapes-subd-mini-tuts-aka-use-the-right-amount-of-geo for some inspiration :)

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of hard to understand your question, but your pictures give me a good idea. Looks like the curved corner is deforming. If you want to simplify your mesh, you can try the following.

- Select the vertices marked in red, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge at Center*
- Select the vertices marked in blue, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge at Center*

[image: 1]